# Ожидание изменения в компоненте webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Здравствуйте!

С очередным вопросом касательно шарпа.
Имеется компонент webbrowser (System.Windows.Forms), форма и кнопка. С помощью webbrowser подгружаю страничку (динамически изменяющуюся после нажатия кнопки), заполняю 2 поля, нажимаю на кнопку.
 1. При заполнении поля необходимо записать переменную состояния.
 2. После нажатия на кнопку переменная состояния изменяется, и её тоже необходимо записать.

Вот мой код:

```
List<string> FirstValue = new List<string>();
List<string> SecondValue  = new List<string>();
...
public void browserGetHasgString()
{
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name_value").SetAttribute("Value", "Вася");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value", "password");
FirestValue.Add(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hash").GetAttribute("value"));
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnSubmit").InvokeMember("click");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  // Ожидание 1 с
SecondValue.Add(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hash").GetAttribute("value"));
}

// Кнопка вызывающая функцию
private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browserGetHeaderString();
    }
```

---

А теперь о проблеме: проблема заключается в том, что нажатие кнопки "не срабатывает", и во вторую переменную записывается такое же значение, что и у первой переменной. Но при этом если смотреть в окно браузера на страничку, нажатие на кнопку срабатывает и в нём отображается страничка после нажатия на кнопку.

---

**upd**
На страничке при нажатии на кнопку происходит обработка входных данных (неведомая ни мне, ни программе), на основании которых создаётся новая переменная.

При "ручных" манипуляциях с webbrowser видно, что происходит нажатие на кнопку: просмотрели код страницы, *записали исходный хэш*, ввели данные, нажали на кнопку, снова посмотрели код страницы, *записали новый хэш*.
Если же провести такие же манипуляции программно (т.е. вводим данные, нажимаем на кнопку), новый хэш не записывается, хотя страничка обновляется.

---

**upd2**
Проблема решилась (увеличил время сна (трединг.слип)).

Comment: Вы бы писали, что пользуетесь winforms. UI-фреймворк у .NET не один.

Comment: А что происходит при нажатии на кнопку? Может быть, старый элемент не исчезает, а просто скрывается, мало ли что.

В общем, приведите достаточно кода, чтобы было понятно, что происходит.

Comment: Гм, но это и есть весь код. Под многоточиями - функция сравнения переменных (hash) из веббраузера, которую ещё не приспособил.
Добавил более развёрнутый комментарий.

Comment: @grandpa: Интересен код странички: что именно происходит при нажатии?

Comment: Разобрался! Проблема была в
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
слишком быстро проходила пауза, из-за чего форма не успевала измениться.
Можно закрывать, извините за пустой топик)